# Trouble changing object value in page, but shows up in console log as working (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, logic

I want to change an object variable `mF` depending on what the user clicks, which will assign an object from an array of objects to the variable `mF`, and also take them to the next "page".

I am using ng-click to assign the objects to `mf` through a function. I'm using `{{ mF.name }}` to test if a new object has been assigned to `mF` and I keep drawing a blank (nothing outputs to page). However, when I assign the object manually within the controller and output using `console.log()`, it's working. Why is it not outputting to the page?

Code:

app.js:

```
app.controller('DeviceController', function($scope) {

$scope.showOptions = false;

var device1 = [
    {
        name: 'PC',
        os: 'Windows',
        chosen: false,
    },
  ...
  ];

var device2 = [
  {...}
  ...
];

var mF = {};

$scope.mF = mF;

console.log(mF);

function calculate (x) {
    mF = device1[x];
}

mF = device1[0];

console.log(mF.name); //outputs correctly in console - "PC"

});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-hide="showOptions">

<div class="osSelect"><span ng-click="calculate(0); showOptions = true">Win</span>
    <span ng-click="calculate(1); showOptions = true">Mac</span> <span ng-click="showOptions = true">test</span></div>
 </div>

<div class="pageHolder2" ng-show="showOptions">

<p>This is the 2nd page: {{ mF.name }}</p> <!-- outputs blank where expression is -->

<span class="back" ng-click="showOptions = false">Back</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to attach the function `calculate` to the scope as well in order to invoke it from the view binding.

So try:

```
$scope.calculate = function calculate (x) {
    $scope.mF = device1[x];
}
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! Do you know why `console.log()` does not need the `$scope`?